# Framework for Hybrid app

Tags: android, ios, vue.js

We have an existing public website built using PHP and JQuery. There are lots of backend logic in PHP including data validations and calls to middle tier through web services and REST APIs. We need to develop an app for Android and iOS without making any changes to the website code base. In addition to that, we need the ability to customize the UI/UX on the mobile app, for e.g. navigation, style sheets, icons etc. In future, we need the ability to use native app features and integrate with hardware like camera, sensors, speakers, GPS etc. What's the best framework to develop this?

- Is Ionic framework even a choice?
- If we use web view to render the
  website on a mobile app, Apple store might block it
- we don't want to
  build the mobile app from scratch
- we would prefer to use Vue.js for
  the app development

Comment: You want to use React Native